# filling a k,k matrix with lower triangular data

Tags: python, matrix

I want to put the output of d2arm as a lower triangular in a k by k matrix. Any advice is welcome.

```
def r(k):
v = np.arange(0, k, 1)
w = abs(v - (k - 1))
return(np.repeat(v, w, axis = None))

def s(k) :
l = pd.DataFrame()
for i in np.arange(1, k): 
    r = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(i, k, 1))
    l = l.append(r)
return(np.array(l)).T

def d2arm(d, f):
k = d.shape[1]
m1 = pd.DataFrame(r(k)).T
m2 = pd.DataFrame(s(k))
H = m2.append(m1)
a = np.array([])
for i in range(H.shape[1]):
        lr = round(f(d.iloc[:, H.iloc[:, i]]), 2)
        a = np.append(a, lr)
return(a)
```

Comment: do you want to replace the upper diagonal values of the matrix by zero?

Comment: f is a function with 2 vectors as input and a scalar as output, a is just a vector. it should fill lower and upper triangular parts of a square matrix

Comment: it is not still clear that how you want to convert the vector `a` to a lower diagonal matrix. say, `a` is k-dimensional, then you want to create a `k x k` lower diagonal square matrix but what value you expect in that matrix? why don't you provide an example with sample input/output?

Comment: a new question will be formulated including a small example